# Plotly Dash Framework has connection time out or limited data size while extracting the data from databases?

Tags: python, dashboard

When I make Dashboards using *Dash Framework*, I want to know if there is a limited connection time or limited data size (in Megabytes or Gigabytes).

In my python scripts (inside Dash Framework),
I will:

- connect to a database
- extract data from database.

When I am extracting data from a database *I want to know what the **limited connection time out** or **limited data size** is*.

When the extraction is done,
I will:

- process the data
- then visualize

Comment: You have to handle this differently, use a job queue like RabbitMQ and process the data asynchronously giving the frontend a unique ticket. The frontend will pool in certain interval, when the data is avaiable, it will show.

Comment: @Epsi95   job queue is available on dash free community version? And i'm also confused that connection time out is related to dash app callback() functions?

Comment: check this https://dash.plotly.com/long-callbacks seems new